# Android touch position

Tags: android, touch, screen

I use the following in the touch gesture listener to report where the user has tapped on the screen

```
String text = "You click at x = " + event.getX() + " and y = " + event.getY();
Toast.makeText(getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This gives the coordinates of the touch in relation to the screen resoloution

What I need is the coordinates of the touch in relation to the bitmap im displaying

My screensize is `800 x 1280` but the image I am displaying ids `6000 x 4000` so i need a way of getting the position of the touch when it is panned to place beyond the initial `800 x1280`

Any Ideas?

mark

EDIT

Code for my imageview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.SubsamplingScaleImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: are you able to get required details when image size is 800 x 1280

Comment: yes if the image is that size and does not move then the result is correct